# ADF Internal methods clarity

Tags: oracle-adf

Which internal method is being called when we set the property "AutoSubmit" to "true"?

I tried my best to find, but was not able to get the exact solution which I want.

Can somebody tell me the answer with ADF and JSF life cycle flow of execution?

Comment: Re-tagged since the tag you used clearly had "Do not use" at the start of its description, and also instructions about what tag to use instead.

Comment: Thank you for re-tagging

Answer (score 1):

I presume  you are using ADF Business components. If you do (better not use  ADF if you don’t):

When setting autosubmit on an input field, the value is propagated to the server the minute user tabs out of the field.
 1. The setter of the attribute on your View Object Row Impl is called .
 2. The setter of the attribute on your Entity Impl is called.

Any processing or business logic you do on View Object or View Row Impl level. Biggest misunderstanding of ADF: trying to do these kind of processing in backing beans. Every Java developer I’ve seen working with ADF does that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you please tell me the ADF and JSF life-cycle flow.!!!

Comment: You don’t need it!!! You shouldn’t care about it.